# Why Is An Error Returning A Whole Document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get a document using `findOne`, I have a simple error handler (`if (err) console.log(err);`), but is returning a whole document. I can't get past this if statement. If I remove the `if (err)`, then it gets caught by another statement which says the document does not exist.

Using Mongoose 5.4.0, have tried removing the if statement but just gets caught by the others saying it doesn't exist. I'm also using discord.js, so wherever it says `message.reply` or `message.channel.send` - it just means that it will send a message to a channel - this has nothing to do with the error.

```
guildModel.findOne({"GuildName": GuildSearch}).then((err, result) => {
    if (result) {
        let guildEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle(GuildSearch)
        .setColor("00ff65")
        .setDescription(result.GuildDescription);
        return message.channel.send(guildEmbed);
     } else {
        let NoDoc = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle("Oops!")
        .setDescription(`<@!${message.author.id}>, There is no Server with the name ${GuildSearch} recorded with me.`)
        .setColor("ff7f00")
        .setFooter("Developed By William#8495");
         return message.channel.send(NoDoc);
      };
}).catch(err => {
    return message.reply("Error: " + err);
});
```

It should just send a field of the document named GuildDescription, but it sends `Error:` and the whole document.

Comment: `.then((err, result) => {...})` your function signature is wrong. It has to be `.then((result) => { ... }, (err) => { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

You are using "Promise style" query so the first argument should be `result`, not `err`:

```
guildModel.findOne({ "GuildName": GuildSearch }).then(result => {
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Or you could use the other syntax:

```
guildModel.findOne({ "GuildName": GuildSearch }, (err, result) => {
  if (err) console.log(err)
});
```

[Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)